# How to unmarshal a json array with different type of value in it

Tags: json, go

For example:

```
{["NewYork",123]}
```

For json array is decoded as a go array, and go array is need to explicit define a type, 
I don't know How to deal with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First that json is invalid, objects has to have keys, so it should be something like `{"key":["NewYork",123]}` or just `["NewYork",123]`.

And when you're dealing with multiple random types, you just use `interface{}`.

```
const j = `{"NYC": ["NewYork",123]}`

type UntypedJson map[string][]interface{}

func main() {
    ut := UntypedJson{}
    fmt.Println(json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &ut))
    fmt.Printf("%#v", ut)
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/3ql_7Da2MU)

Answer (score 3):

> The json package uses map[string]interface{} and []interface{} values to store arbitrary JSON objects and arrays...
>   http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go

Each value in an object must have key. So suppose this is your json :

```
{"key":["NewYork",123]}
```

Then your code should be like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Message map[string]interface{}

func main() {
    msg := Message{}
    s := `{"key":["Newyork",123]}`
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &msg)
    fmt.Println(msg, err)
}
```

You can run it : http://play.golang.org/p/yihj6BZHBY

Comment: For that specific case `map[string][]interface{}` is better since he's always expecting an array.

Comment: I just followed here: http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go . However, what you offer is sensible too, for this case.

Comment: `map[string]interface{}` is perfectly fine if you're expecting the value to be other things besides null or array.