# Unmarshal JSON Array of arrays in Go

Tags: arrays, json, go, struct

I want to parse some json data in go. The data looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "someId",
    "key_1": "value_1",
    "key_2": "value_2",
    "key_3": "value_3",
    "points": [
        [
            1487100466412,
            "50.032178",
            "8.526018",
            300,
            0.0,
            26,
            0
        ],
        [
            1487100471563,
            "50.030869",
            "8.525949",
            300,
            0.0,
            38,
            0
        ],
        [
            1487100475722,
            "50.028514",
            "8.525959",
            225,
            0.0,
            69,
            -900
        ],
        [
            1487100480834,
            "50.025827",
            "8.525793",
            275,
            0.0,
            92,
            -262
        ]
    ]
}
```

I built a go struct:

```
type SomeStruct struct {
   ID   string `json:"id"`
   Key1 string `json:"key_1"`
   Key2 string `json:"key_2"`
   Key3 string `json:"key_3"`
   Points []Point `json:"points"`
}

type Point struct {
   Timestamp int64 `json:"0"`
   Latitude float64 `json:"1,string"`
   Longitude float64 `json:"2,string"`
   Altitude int `json:"3"` 
   Value1 float64 `json:"4"`
   Value2 int `json:"5"`
   Value3 int `json:"6"`      
}
```

I unmarshal the json data

```
var track SomeStruct
error := json.Unmarshal(data,&track)
if(error != nil){
    fmt.Printf("Error while parsing data: %s", error)
}
```

> json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type Point{someId value_1 value_2 value_3 [{0 0 0 0 0 0 0} {0 0 0 0 0 0 0} {0 0 0 0 0 0 0}...]}

So the first json keys are parsed correctly, but I cannot figure out how to get the point data, which is an array of arrays.

The generate struct is also the suggest one from here, except I don't use a nested struct but a separate type. Using the suggested nested struct does not make a difference:
[JSON-to-Go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/)

Do I need to implement my own Unmarshaller for this?

======= UPDATE SOLUTION ============

It is enough to implement the UnmarshalJSON interface for the Point struct.
The example below does not contain proper error handling but it show the direction.

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/O9-JlEAKcq)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type SomeStruct struct {
    ID     string  `json:"id"`
    Key1   string  `json:"key_1"`
    Key2   string  `json:"key_2"`
    Key3   string  `json:"key_3"`
    Points []Point `json:"points"`
}

type Point struct {
    Timestamp int64
    Latitude  float64
    Longitude float64
    Altitude  int
    Value1    float64
    Value2    int16
    Value3    int16
}

func (tp *Point) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var v []interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error whilde decoding %v\n", err)
        return err
    }
    tp.Timestamp = int64(v[0].(float64))
    tp.Latitude, _ = strconv.ParseFloat(v[1].(string), 64)
    tp.Longitude, _ = strconv.ParseFloat(v[2].(string), 64)
    tp.Altitude = int(v[3].(float64))
    tp.Value1 = v[4].(float64)
    tp.Value2 = int16(v[5].(float64))
    tp.Value3 = int16(v[6].(float64))

    return nil
}

func main() {

    const data = `{"id":"someId","key_1":"value_1","key_2":"value_2","key_3":"value_3","points":[[1487100466412,"50.032178","8.526018",300,0.0,26,0],[1487100471563,"50.030869","8.525949",300,0.0,38,0],[1487100475722,"50.028514","8.525959",225,0.0,69,-900],[1487100480834,"50.025827","8.525793",275,0.0,92,-262]]}`

    var something SomeStruct
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &something)

    fmt.Printf("%v", something)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unmarshal a json array with different type of value in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326644/how-to-unmarshal-a-json-array-with-different-type-of-value-in-it)

Comment: thanks, replacing Points `[]Point \`json:"points"\`` with `Points interface{}` at least parses the data, which makes sense to me. 
But how can i get a typed value instead of the empty interface?

Comment: By using type assertion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934909/golang-type-assertion

Comment: You want it to be of type `[][]interface{}` Then you can index the individual values.

Comment: Hrm, nevermind my previous comments, went to play and what I thought would work isn't working..

Comment: @chrisdo the solution should be posted as a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), not as an edit into the question. See [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to implement my own Unmarshaller for this?

Yes.

You're trying to unmarshal an array into a struct (`Point`), which means you need to tell the JSON unmarshaler how the array values map to the struct values.

Also note that your tags are incorrect in your `Point` definition. json tags refer to the key names, but arrays don't have keys (in JavaScript they can be accessed as if they do, but this isn't JavaScript).  In other words, `json:"0"` will only work if your JSON looks like `{"0":123}`. If you implement your own unmarshaler, you can just get rid of those json tags.

Comment: Just a note. Only an Unmarshaller for the array itself needs to be written. The array will unmarshal into a `[][]interface{}` of points. That is the portion that will need to be handled manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will play with this. I managed to use type assertion to get the values from the Points, but using a custom unmarshaller for the array sounds cleaner to me. I will update Post as soon as I got it right.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear: I think the proper approach is to unmarshal the pointer data to `[]interface{}`. The standard JSON marshaler will already handle the `[]Point` part.

Answer (score 12):

The JSON:

```
[
  {
    "type": "Car",
    "wheels": 4
  },
  {
    "type": "Motorcycle",
    "wheels": 2
  }
]
```

The Struct:

```golang
type Vehicle struct {
  Type   string
  Wheels int
}
```

The Unmarshaller:

```golang
func TestVehicleUnmarshal(t *testing.T) {
    response := `[{"type": "Car","wheels": 4},{"type": "Motorcycle","wheels": 2}]`

    var vehicles []Vehicle
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(response), &vehicles)

    assert.IsType(t, Vehicle{}, vehicles[0])
    assert.EqualValues(t, "Car", vehicles[0].Type)
    assert.EqualValues(t, 4, vehicles[0].Wheels)
    assert.EqualValues(t, "Motorcycle", vehicles[1].Type)
    assert.EqualValues(t, 2, vehicles[1].Wheels)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/5SfDH-XZt9J

Comment: I keep forgetting I can do a slice of structs! Thanks!